# How to have a custom audio for a Voiceover element?

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover, siri

Now, our app, pikSpeak Camera, was recently found useful to blind iOS community as it allowed to capture photos with sound as it allowed them to easily navigate through older pics just using the the audio tags.

The issue that I am facing is that I want to override the Voiceover audio tag associated with an element when a user selects it and instead have a custom audio in the UICollectionViewController cell selection.

Basically, I guess it's easy to disable the VO tag audio but then how do I play a custom audio on VO selection?